# Mongoid associations & references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mongoid

I have a newbie question about associations in Mongoid. I have these two models

```
class Manufacturer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :url, type: String

  has_many :products
end
```

and

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :manufacturer_name, type :String
  field :model, type: String
  field :price, type: Float

  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

Now I create a new company:

```
man = Manufacturer.create name: 'Flower Power Companies', url: 'www.flowerpower.com'
```

and a new product:

```
prod = Product.create manufacturer_name: what_comes_here, model: 'Foo0815', price: '19.90'
```

How to reference prod.manufacturer_name to man.name? If man.name will be changed, prod.manufacturer_name should be changed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you already have a relation between the two why you need to have a cloumn manufacture_name in your products table.

Just do

```
m = Manufacture.create name: "...", url: "..."
p = m.products.create model: ".." , price : 19.90
```

This will automatically create a relation between your manufacture and your product. Later when you want to know the manufacture's name simply call p.manufacture.name

When you create a new product and wish to add manufacture later to the product then just do

```
p = Product.create model: "",price: ""
p.manufacture = Manufacture.find(:id)
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to be the way I am looking for. I'm coding on a JSON API backend, so products should contain a field which represents the manufacturer. I'll play with that ...

Comment: Huh, have forgotten one more detail:

Comment: m = Manufacturer.create name: "Old name", url: "www.foobar.com"
p = m.products.create model: "Superduper" , price: 19.90 

p.manufacturer.name returns what I'm expecting: "Old name" Then I change the name of the manufacturer:

foo = Manufacturer.first
foo.name = "New name"
foo.save!

... but p.manufacturer.name returns still "Old name". Any hints for this? Btw, the MongoDB contains only this one Element, so .first refs the right document.

Comment: It happened because product instance is already loaded in memory. You should do p.reload.manufacturer.name if you changed associated model in console. In normal web app flow you change manufacturer name in one request and list products in another, so it should be an issue.